# How to parse files according to their extension

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, fileparsing

I've a situation where there are different types of files (of different extension) in some of the directories. I've no idea what type of file is present in a particular directory. Let's assume the following case:

There is a common path to all five directories 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/1/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/2/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/3/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/4/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/5/
```

In short, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are in dir3.

As an example,
directories 1 and 3 have files with extension **.txt**
directories 2, 4, 5 have files with extension **.gz**

I'm doing this as of now:

```
while [ $a -le 5 ]
    do
        cat /dir1/dir2/dir3/"$a"/*.txt | grep "string" > /path/output"$a"
        zcat -f /dir1/dir2/dir3/"$a"/*.gz | grep "string" > /path/output"$a"
        ((a++))
    done
```

Outputs are created but few of them are blank. I'm sure that inputs have that string I used in **grep**. I think the script I'm using is over-writing the files.

How can I perform this by searching the file extension first, and performing either cat or zcat accordingly? Please suggest?

Edit:

I've also tried the following:

```
while [ $a -le 5 ]
    do  

for f in /dir1/dir2/dir3/"$a"/*.txt
  do  
      cat $f | grep "string" > /path/output"$a"  
  done  
for f in /dir1/dir2/dir3/"$a"/*.gz
  do  
      cat $f | grep "string" > /path/output"$a"  
  done   

done
```

Comment: You edited attempt should work as long as you use `shopt -s nullglob`. This prevents one or the other `for` loop from being entered at all. If, for whatever reason, you do end up with `gz` and `txt` files in the same directory, the result of the `gz` loop will overwrite the result of the `txt` loop.

Comment: @chepner Yes. It's wokring fine if I redirect the output to different directories - one for .txt and one for .gz.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the txt files in one array, and if that array is not empty, run `cat`. Otherwise, run `zcat`. The output of whichever one actually runs gets redirected to the output file.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for d in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    txt=(/dir1/dir2/dir3/"$d"/*.txt)
    if (( ${#txt[@]} )); then
        grep "string" "${txt[@]}"
    else
        zcat -f /dir1/dir2/dir3/"$a"/*.gz | grep "string"
    fi > /path/output/"$d"
done
```